# How to create a new .cshtml page in a project that can be seen through a URL

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, razor

I am using Visual Studio to create a new website. I have a new page called test.cshtml with valid html inside in my solution files. I am trying to open it to debug in a browser, but every time I do it just shows a 404 error with no explanation as to what/why it is not being found. If I open it in Visual Studio view it still shows a 404 error never showing my html.

What do I have to do to create a new page I can navigate to from a browser if you don't just add an .cshtml page into the project files and navigate to that path in a browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC, URLs map to controller actions, not files on the web server.  MVC Views (.cshtml files) need to be rendered by the Razor engine.  You need to create a controller action that renders your .cshtml view.  In the example below, replace `YourController` with the appropriate name and replace `YourAction` with the name of your .cshtml view.  Then you can navigate to this page by hitting `yourdomain.com/YourController/YourAction`.

```
public class YourController: Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /YourController/

    public ActionResult YourAction()
    {
        // Add action logic here
        return View("YourAction");
    }
}
```

More reading about ASP.NET MVC controllers/actions: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/aspnet-mvc-controllers-overview-cs